# Why Quora doesn't grab proper image thumbnail from meta tags?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, meta-tags, social-media, quora

I've published an article on the blog and tried to share it on Quora.

I've set up proper og:image tags, and twitter card tags I've verified that using Facebook Open Graph debugger.

**Unfortunately, sharing this article on Quora doesn't work as expected.**

Quora, for a thumbnail, sets the first image in the content of the html (a logo), instead of grabbing the one specified in the `og:image` tag (article cover photo)

Below is the affected URL:

https://driggl.com/blog/a/why-we-are-not-dry

#### Notes

- Facebook debugger do not return any errors nor warnings.
- Sharing on slack/Fb/twitter works well
- The image Proportions are the ones that FB suggests (1.9x1)
- with JS disabled everything still loads the same.

**Does anybody have an idea why is it happening?**

#### Screenshots:

**Expected behaviour**
[image: expected behavior]

**Current behavior:**
[image: Wrong thumbnail when sharing an article on Quora]

**Technology used:**

- This micro project is written in Nuxt.js and metadata are server-rendered
- is open-sourced: https://github.com/driggl/blog

#### Update

After a lot of debugging, I've found, that:

1. After writing the quick basic project in Next (React), I got the same issue.
2. Quora seems to ignore image meta tags on this page.
3. When I place the image that is loaded in the same domain, Quora can grab the thumbnail without issues.
4. When image is loaded from AWS S3 directly, Quora doesn't load it.

I came with a monkey patch:

1. Configure PROXY to load images from within the same domain the project is hosted on
2. Add 1x1 px image at the top of the html body so quora can grab it.

But this question remains Unanswered, as I don't see this hacky stuff as a proper answer.

Comment: You might have to reach out to Quora staff. I recall having a similar issue with Twitter not properly displaying meta tags and I contacted their support and we resolved the issue.

Comment: I already did, but their support does not respond quickly :)